# Alignment issue on the Stack Overflow talent page

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-talent

There is an alignment issue on the [Stack Overflow Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) page, call out form in the Google Chrome browser.

The bottom of the div is not aligned properly in the Chrome alone. In Internet Explorer and Firefox it is fine.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Call out Form]

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 
Chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) 
Firefox: 50.1.0 
Zoom: 100%

Comment: adding the browser version and OS will be useful to them. I can't repro on my Chrome 56.0.2924.87.